# PHP MYSQL brings answer that aren't in it

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem.
I did the Code below (no Comments cause of the bad coding).
In my DB there is one row with the id = 1 and the name = Ole.
But when I write "  echo "$result " ;  " It says "Yannik".
Don't know why pls help:D

```
 <?php 
   session_start();     
   require_once ("config.php");

   $Benutzer = $_SESSION['Name'] ;

   $sql = "SELECT bla From test WHERE id = 1 "; 

   $res= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

   $result=$res['bla'];   

   echo "$result </br>" ;   
?>
```

Comment: This means that name is `Yannik` or you don't show us full code.

Comment: You aren't selecting `name`, you are selecting `bla`.

Comment: COde doesn't fit the description; and we have no idea what's in your database... Please help us help you!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row["bla"];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

you hadnot converted the $res to an array.
Use 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);